# How to rig a 3D arm to the footage of my real arm in movie.

Tags: animation, rigging, rigid-body-simulation, video

Hello I have only been using blender for a little while but I have a project I want to work on. I have created a 3D model of my real arm in blender in a rock form. I want to be able to capture my arm on video and have the 3d model move with my motion and also change from my real skin to the rock form almost like beast in x-men. I think it's simple but that I'm not doing something correct. Please help me. Thank You.

Comment: or use video tracking...

Comment: can you do Motion tacking with just a dslr camera

Comment: All the motion tracking will be happening in Blender, so you could technically do it with a Logitech webcam.

Comment: you just need an up-to-date Blender.

Comment: Okay so after taking to footage of the film how to a make this real arm turn to this animation?

Comment: You need to take the footage into the Movie Clip Editor.
Track it and do Object Solving. 
Too long to explain on this format but watch Sebastian Koenig's tutorial here.. http://www.blender3d.org/e-shop/product_info_n.php?products_id=147  Things have changed in the interface since that tutorial, but the workflow remains the same. Look for the **Track, Match, Blend!** videos.

Comment: Actually there is a newer version of the ***Track,Match,Blend!*** in blendercloud https://cloud.blender.org/training/track-match-blend-2/